# Can a default user's password be set in SQL using PHP's password_hash?

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

My old PHP app has a default admin user and md5 encrypted password created by the SQL that creates the database: `insert into users values ( 1, 'admin', MD5('changeMe'), 2 );`

Is there a simple way to include a default user and encrypted password using PHP's passowrd_hash function on creating the tables? I ask because I understand that password_hash is a native PHP function and I assume it won't be understood in SQL.

Comment: You could just `echo password_hash('changeMe');` in a PHP interpreter and use the result string in the query.

Comment: Generate the hash with `password_hash` and *then* insert it.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing an access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Any modern [development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in, and there are [authentication libraries](http://phprbac.net/) you can use. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: Will try the approach of @Nick and tadman. For the longer term I will try writing an installer to insert into an empty user table.

Comment: What you're describing here is often called "database seeds", as in things you need to add to the database to bootstrap from nothing. Many frameworks have a formal way to declare these. In your own ad-hoc application you'll need to invent and document your own approach. You could create a SQL file if you do the result of `echo password_hash('defaultpassword')` for example. Keep in mind it's usually best to generate a random password during the seeding process and echo that to the screen so the user can make use of it.

Comment: That's what I'm working on @tadman--except for the random password. I plan to generate it from the user's entry in a form and collect the variable in `$hash = password_hash($pass)`, then insert $hash into the $sql. The problem is not that the application is ad hoc, which it's not, but that it's written (2003) in PHP ≤5 and an old MySQL. What is ad hoc is my trying to keep the working parts and update what's not working or working well. It's the  Windows XP of my life.

Comment: Yes, there is. What have you tried so far, and where are you stuck? Is there any problem in using the generated hash instead of that MD5 part in your query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to my problem came in three parts. My OP sought a simple way to create a hashed password for the admin user for insertion in the MySQL database on the installation of the application, using the native PHP `password_hash()` function.

(1) Based on a suggestion by @Nick and @Tadman, I decided to incorporate setting the hash in an installer script that would set not only the hash but other defined site/application variables.

Rather than inserting user values when the database table is created, it was deferred until immediately after, with the admin user entering their credentials in the form that inserts the hash and writes other definitions to a file:

```
$userpass = $_POST['userpass'];
echo password_hash($userpass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

(2) The second part of my problem was replacing all instances of ``` md5()`` with ```password_hash()` and I achieved that by using a neat PHP [script](https://www.phpclasses.org/package/8948-PHP-Search-and-replace-strings-in-text-files.html) I found online to recursively search and replace the occurrences on the server.

Having replaced the `md5()` occurrences, I needed to change the hash comparison method and again by searching the relevant files I was able to replace instances of:

```
if ($p != $theUser->pwd ) {
    return( false );     }
```

with:

```
if(password_verify($p, $theUser->pwd)) {
    // Success!
    }
else {
    // Invalid credentials
echo "Uh oh!";
    }
```

(3) The third step in resolving the problem was [discovering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php#113493) that adding $1$ to the opening of the md5 hash could make it readable by `password_hash();` so I just needed to make a couple of adjustments in the installed database to the admin user's old password.

Thanks to those who helped shine the light so I could find my way. I'm off now to invent the wheel and sliced bread.

Answer (score -2):

you can do something like this in php:

```
$hash = password_hash('changeMe'); 
//echo $hash;
```

then use this hash in the Database.

Comment: Because MD5 has absolutely no business whatsoever being used to store passwords.

Comment: Giving your password to some sketchy site seems like trouble. This can be generated locally using a single line of PHP code.

Comment: He wanted to have a "default" password, the tool above simply generates the hash without storing. my suggestion was only because he wanted a "simple" way to generate those hashes.

Comment: EbrahimMohammed, I agree with @tadman re going to some unknown site. More importantly, that doesn't simplify things but complicates them, going to a remote site instead of natively achieving the end inside the app--**achieved with one line of code** as it turns out.

Comment: Ah. that makes sense then! Learned something new today :O I sometimes use the website to be honest - but only when testing locally tho

Comment: Appreciate you're trying to help here, don't get me wrong, but sometimes an answer is counter-productive. It might be worth editing or deleting this to avoid confusing someone else looking for answers.